# UIPickerView, signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a trouble with signal SIGABRT, but I think that everything is ok.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var vysledek: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cisloJedna: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cisloDva: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var znamenkoVyber: UIPickerView!
    var array = ["*", "/", "+", "-"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        znamenkoVyber.delegate = self
        znamenkoVyber.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count;
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return array[row]
    }

    @IBAction func vypocitej(_ sender: Any) {
        if array == ["*"] {
            let vypocet = String(Int(cisloJedna.text!)! * Int(cisloDva.text!)!)
            vysledek.text = vypocet
        }
        else if array == ["/"] {
            let vypocet = String(Int(cisloJedna.text!)! / Int(cisloDva.text!)!)
            vysledek.text = vypocet
        }
        else if array == ["+"] {
            let vypocet = String(Int(cisloJedna.text!)! + Int(cisloDva.text!)!)
            vysledek.text = vypocet
        }
        else if array == ["-"] {
            let vypocet = String(Int(cisloJedna.text!)! - Int(cisloDva.text!)!)
            vysledek.text = vypocet
        }
    }
}
```

Where can the problem be?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: line didn`t show error, but this showed me an error..

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: it`s old... i tried it, but it`s didn`t work..

Comment: Have you tried breakpoints? BTW máš fb nebo nějakej kontakt ? :D

Comment: @Phyber This is an English site. Please keep comments in English.